# USB to serial Adapter not working after upgrade to El Capitan

Tags: usb

I have been using a TRENDnet TU-S9 USB to serial adapter for a couple years.

When I upgraded OSX from 10.10 Yosemite to 10.11 El Capitan, it stopped working.

I've tried reinstalling the driver, but that did not fix it.

I ran `ioreg -p IOUSB` and could still see the device, which is a good sign.

```
...    
+-o USB-Serial Controller D@14200000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x100000533, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (6 ms), retain 11>
...
```

Unfortunately `/dev` does not contain `tty.usbserial` when my adapter is connected.

How do I get OSX to create `/dev/tty.usbserial` when I connect my adapter?

Comment: Best guess would be look/wait for an updated driver - always an issue with a major OS update... don't jump until you are certain all your esoterica has functional drivers. I can't use El Cap until my pro audio rig has updated drivers... or unless I don't want to earn a living in the meantime...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prolific has a new driver out that works with El Cap: http://www.prolific.com.tw/US/ShowProduct.aspx?p_id=229&pcid=41

Comment: Jan Lehnardt provided a working driver. Thank you, I have tested and confirmed running Mac OS 10.11.1 with zterm and alcatel switches.